# min/max/saddle points of $z=2(x-1)^2+3(y-2)^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$z=2(x-1)^2+3(y-2)^2$$

$Z_x:4(x-1)=0\Rightarrow x=1 $

$Z_y: 6(y-2)=0\Rightarrow 6y=12 \Rightarrow y=2$

$Z_{xx}:4>0$

$Z_{yy}: 6>0$

$Z_{xy}=Z_{yx}=0$

so the $\text{det}(H)>0$ so it is minimum point? when will it be a saddle? when $\text{det}(H)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $z(x,y)$ has a minimum at (1,2).  There is no saddle point or maximum.  $z$ would have a saddle point at (1,2) if you flipped the sign of either coefficient, and a maximum at (1,2) if you flipped the sign of both coefficients.

Generally, for a function $f(x)$, if $H(x)$ denotes the Hessian matrix, a sufficient condition for a point $x^*$ to be a local minimum (maximum) is if $H(x^*)>0$ ($H(x^*)<0$) and $\nabla f(x^*) = 0.$  To answer your question, the existence of a saddle point at $x$ does not necessarily imply that $H(x)$ is singular.  Roughly speaking, it implies that some eigenvalues of $H(x)$ are nonpositive and some are nonnegative, which can occur for nonsingular $H(x)$, and we call such matrices indefinite.

Comment: I saw that some use this $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy}^2)$ and if $D<0$ is it a saddle point and if $D=0$ more test need to be done

Comment: @gbox the equation you have for $D$ is the determinant of the Hessian $H$ from my answer.  However, positive and negative (semi)definiteness of $H$ has to do with the roots of the characteristic polynomial ${{\rm det}}(H-\lambda I)$. Just taking the determinant of $H$ is not entirely relevant for finding critical points of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that if $\text{det}(H) = 0$, then there is a saddle point. There is simply no saddle point as you already found out that $\text{det}(H) > 0, \forall (x,y) $ of $\mathbb{R^2}$